# HTML5 date picker not flipping when the body is in RTL

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, right-to-left

I have a material UI React application that can be changed to 'RTL(Right To Left)' when in the appropriate time zones. But the HTML5 date picker I use does not flip when the body in in RTL. If I use a custom Date Picker, that flips though. Is there a way I can make HTML5 date picker align with RTL?

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-noyce-46r7j?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can wrappe your HTML5 date picker inside the grid of MUI

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={enGB}>
        <Grid container justify="space-around">
          <TextField
            id="need-before-date"
            variant="outlined"
            type="date"
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
          />
        </Grid>
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: That does not work- I tried - https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-noyce-46r7j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yeah my idea is to wrappe your TextField inside the grid .. in your second example, you miss wrapping it

Comment: I did exactly the way you said. It does not move the icon to the left.